# How does the structure work in C internally? How is a data copy made from one structure to another?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64

Well, I know how the structure works in C, but I don't know how it works internally, because I'm still learning assembly, I'm at the beginning, well, my question is, in the code below I have a structure called P and create two variables from From this structure called A and B, after assigning A to B, thus being B = A, I can get the data from A, even without using a pointer, how is this copy of the data from A to B made?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct P{
    int x;
    int y;
}A, B;

int main(void) {
   printf("%p\n%p\n\n", &A, &B);
   printf("Member x of a: %p\nMember y of a: %p\n", &A.x, &A.y);
   printf("Member x of b: %p\nMember y of b: %p\n", &B.x, &B.y);  
   A.x = 10;
   A.y = 15;
   B = A; // 10 
   printf("%d\n%d\n", B.x, B.y);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The data is copied from one structure to the other.  How this is exactly done depends on the compiler, but typically it's a bunch of loads followed by a bunch of stores.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. When you have two variables, “int a, b;” and you assign one to another, “b = a;” do you understand how that works? What do you see as different when they are structures?

Comment: @fuz, in this case A and B are probably in registers. (Well, they would be if the first trace statements weren’t there.)

Comment: I want to understand how it works in assembly, I already listed the code in assembly, but I did not quite understand. I want to know how the compiler manages to get the data that is in A and put it in B, without using pointers

Comment: @YuriAlbuquerque Internally, the compiler likely does use pointers to keep track of the structures.  Your question cannot be answered in general beyond “the data is copied” because what actually happens varies wildly depending on the compiler, architecture, and optimisation settings.

Comment: Yes, you really have to use pointers internally, but I wanted to know how this process is done in gcc

Comment: You can imagine `B = A;` translated to `memcpy(&B, &A, sizeof(B));`.  An implementation (a compiler) can choose many different ways to do it, depending on many factors, but this one is easy to understand.

Comment: The structure assignment in C is essentially equivalent to `memmove(&B, &A, sizeof(A))`.  The elements of B can subsequently be changed without affecting A; likewise, the elements of A can subsequently be changed without affecting B.  If the structure contains pointers, the pointers are copied verbatim — there is no deep copy involved.  If the structure does contain pointers, then the 'post assignment' independence does not extend to the data pointed to; if you change that pointed-to data via one structure, it changes for the other too because they share the pointed at data.

Comment: You claim you "already listed the code in assembly" so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57129164/edit) that code into the post and ask a specific question about the part that is unclear. Anyway, variables have addresses which can be used as pointers obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interesting thing in your sample code, I think, is the line

```
B = A;
```

Typically, the compiler implements this in one of two ways.

(1) It copies the members individually, giving more or less exactly the same effect as if you had said

```
B.x = A.x;
B.y = A.y;
```

(2) It emits a low-level byte-copy loop (or machine instruction), giving the effect of

```
memcpy(&B, &A, sizeof(struct P));
```

(except that typically this is done in-line, with no actual function call involved).

The compiler will choose one or the other of these based on which one is smaller (less emitted code), or which one is more efficient, or whatever the compiler is trying to optimize for.

Comment: `memcpy` itself normally *does* inline for small constant sizes :P.  On ISAs with SIMD registers (like x86's SSE2 XMM registers), the copy is often done 16 bytes at a time.  Also, you don't need to manually cast to `(void*)`.  In C, any pointer can implicitly cast to `void*`.

Comment: And from `void*` too.

Comment: Sigh, I guess I've been doing too much C++ lately.  (Fixed.)

Comment: compilers like clang have a command line option to not use memcpy, otherwise it does.  gcc, dont remember off hand, its trivial to compile then examine the assembly or disassemble and see how they implemented for that version of compiler for that target on that day.

Answer (score 1):

Your example limits what the compiler can do, basically mandating that the struct exist in memory.  First, you're instructing the compiler to create A & B as globals, and, second, you are taking the address of the struct (and its fields) for your printf statement.  Due to either of these, the compiler will choose memory as the placement for these structs.

However, since they are each only two int's in size, copy between them would take only two mov instructions (some architectures) or two loads and two stores (other architectures).

Yet, if you were working with these structs as local variables and/or parameters as is commonly done with these kind of small structs — and provided you did not take their addresses — these would frequently be optimized by the compiler to place the entire struct into the cpu registers.  For example, A.x might get a cpu register, and A.y also its own register.  Now, a copy or pass as of A as parameter (which is like an assignment) is just a pair of register `mov`s (if even that is required, as the compiler might choose the proper registers in the first place).  In other words, unless the user program forces the struct to memory, the compiler has the freedom to treat the struct as a pair of rather separate int's.  So, by contrast, potentially rather different and more efficient.

The compiler can also do other kinds of optimizations, one involving remembering the constant values that were assigned (as so do constant assigns again with B instead of copies from A's memory), and another involving eliminating A and the assignments to A and doing assignments directly to B, as A is merely copied into B and not used later.  Among other things, to reiterate from above, having the structs be local variables helps some of these optimizations as does not taking their addresses.

Comment: Grateful for the answer